# Rust, compute gcd: modularity, references

Tags: beginner, rust

This is my first time trying Rust. I wrote this code to compute the greater common divisor of 2 integers. Any advice to improve it? Am I using modularity/reference/borrow/dereference the correct way?

File `src/gcd.rs`:

```
// calculate the gcd of two integers
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

pub fn gcd(a: &i64, b: &i64) -> i64 {
    let mut _a = *a;
    let mut _b = *b;
    while _b != 0 {
        let tmp = _a;
        _a = _b;
        _b = tmp % _b;
    }
    _a
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use ::gcd;

    #[test]
    fn test_gcd() {
        assert_eq!(gcd::gcd(&60, &168), 12);
        assert_eq!(gcd::gcd(&1071, &1029), 21);
    }
}
```

File `src/main.rs`:

```
mod gcd;

fn main() {
    println!("gcd({}, {}) = {}", 60, 168, gcd::gcd(&60, &168)); 
}
```

Directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── gcd.rs
│   └── main.rs
└── target
    ├── ...
```

Comment: Rolled back Rev 3 → 2. If you have difficulty understanding an answer, please write a comment on that answer.

Comment: @Jamal: how to write properly formatted question in the comments??

Comment: @NicolasC: Just the way you've already done it (comments don't make code appear the exact same way as they do in posts).

Answer (score 3):

1. You do not need to take the numbers by reference.
2. Do *not* put an underscore at the beginning of the variable name. A variable name beginning with `_` is used to say to the compiler that the variable is unused.

Otherwise, I see no issues in your code. Here is the solution taking account of my comments:

```
pub fn gcd(mut a: i64, mut b: i64) -> i64 {
    while b != 0 {
        let tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp % b;
    }
    a
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use ::gcd;

    #[test]
    fn test_gcd() {
        assert_eq!(gcd(60, 168), 12);
        assert_eq!(gcd(1071, 1029), 21);
    }
}
```

### Further explanations:

> Why do I need to use `let a =` instead of `let mut a =` when calling it?

Not sure if my explanation is legit, but when you **give** a thing to another function, this function can do whatever it wants to this thing: it can take it as mutable or not. That is not anymore the problem of the previous owner.

> Which type of variables should and should not be passed by reference?

This is a very broad question. I advice you to think things differently. In Rust, you can **give** a thing, or only lend it (the thing is **borrowed**). The general answer is: if you do not need anymore the thing, or if the receiver needs a full control on it, give it away.

In this specific case, the thing is copyable and small (as small as a reference, in fact). So, borrow it does not give any advantage: just take it (or take a copy) and do not bother with references.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that you can (and did) put the `mut` in the argument list. That's not obvious to many newcomers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Some questions about making the gcd function parameters mutable; assuming I'm calling it with the following:

`let a = 60; let b = 168; println!("gcd({}, {}) = {}", a, b, gcd::gcd(a, b));`

- why do I need to use let a = instead of let mut a = when calling it?
- why aren't the values of a and b modified by side effect of the function (that's why I did a defensive copy in the first place)?
- which type of variables should and should not be passed by reference?

Comment: @NicolasC Simply said, to the right of the `:` you specify how the data is passed to the function and to the left you describe how the function should interpret that data.

Comment: @NicolasC I answered your question 1 and 3, not sure about what you meant in the 2nd one, though.